# Magento 2 Multiple Sales Order Grid(Duplicate) as per order Status

Tags: magento2, order-grid

I am looking for solution for multiple sales order Grid as per order status.
One grid will have all pending order and another grid for Processing orders.

Please have a look attached screenshot.

[image]

how is this possible?Please give me an idea for that.

Comment: Have you use any third party extension for Order related? Then try to disable and then check.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya,search on forums but not found such type of extension.

Comment: No I am asking currenlty if you use any third party extension related to any order related functionlity then try to disable and then check, does it working fine or not.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya,no,just Magento2 default.There is not any issue just I want to implement that functionality as per screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Hi if your need multiple Order Grid based on status then you need to create module for that Create below file for your module as usual create

```
registration.php
etc/module.xml
```

Create your module namespace for Admin area in **etc/adminhtml/routes.xml** file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="multiordergrid" frontName="multiordergrid">
            <module name="Vendor_Multiordergrid" before="Vendor_Multiordergrid" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now create menu for seprate Grid show in **etc/adminhtml/menu.xml** as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Multiordergrid::manager" title="Multi Order Grid" module="Vendor_Multiordergrid" sortOrder="10" resource="Vendor_Multiordergrid::manager"/>
        <add id="Vendor_Multiordergrid::pending" title="Pending Order" module="Vendor_Multiordergrid" sortOrder="0" parent="Vendor_Multiordergrid::manager"
                action="multiordergrid/sales/pending" resource="Vendor_Multiordergrid::pending"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Create Controller file for pending action of your module in **Controller/adminhtml/Sales/Pending.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Multiordergrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Sales;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory) {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Create your pending Action layout file in **view/adminhtml/layout/multiordergrid_sales_pending.xml** as below

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="sales_order_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now you can see the order grid in your Layout, Now we need to filter the order collection for the our Layout Grid for that create **etc/di.xml** file and override the order Grid collection file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Multiordergrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Now create **Collection.php** file as below file **Vendor\Multiordergrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Multiordergrid\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

class Collection extends OriginalCollection {
    protected $_authSession;
    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger,
        FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession
    ) {
        $this->_authSession = $authSession;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager);
    }

    protected function _renderFiltersBefore() {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $request = $objectManager->get("\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http");

        $moduleName = $request->getModuleName();
        $controller = $request->getControllerName();
        $action = $request->getActionName();

        $url = $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        if ($moduleName == "mui" && $controller == "index" && $action == "render") {
            $url = $_COOKIE["current_url"];
        }

        if (strpos($url, 'multiordergrid/sales/pending') !== false) {
            setcookie("current_url", $url, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
            $this->getSelect()->where("status = 'pending'");
        }

        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
}
```

now run Magento basic command and check your pending grid it will show only order with pending status

Please follow above steps for all Magento order status.

Thank you

Comment: thanks for your effort.I will check and share you.

Comment: does it resolved or not ?

Comment: this is creating new menu grid while I need the same sales order grid exactly same attached screenshot.